# Open blender file through Python API

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to open a *.blend through the Python API (outside of blender)? I have tried bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="my_file_path") but when I run it, the program crashes.

It reads the file:

Read blend: untitled.blend

Error: Not freed memory blocks: 25889, total unfreed memory 8.830418 MB

But exits right after.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hello ! Do you mean you want to run a script with an external program ? Then you should read the docs : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/index.html

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand though, you can't access the python API outside of blender if that's your question. You can however launch blender headless to access the API

Comment: Hi there @Gorgious! I meant loading a file with blender as a Python module, without running it on the background. As to then edit it with the API. I'm sorry if I sound to confusing, I'm quite new to blender.